# How to display a message when a form input is valid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I'm having a hard time to display a message when an input is valid. To display error messages, it is working alright. This is what I'm trying:

```
<form>
...
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="inputSuccess">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <input type="text" id="inputUser" name="usernameInput" class="form-control textbox" 
                               placeholder="Digite seu Username" width="25" ng-model="username.value" 
                               ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="10" valid="validateForm.usernameInput.$valid" required>
                        <div ng-if="validateForm.usernameInput.$dirty" ng-messages="validateForm.usernameInput.$error">
                            <div class="error-message" ng-message="required">*This field is required</div>
                            <div class="error-message" ng-message="minlength">*Username too short</div>
                            <div class="error-message" ng-message="maxlength">*Username too long</div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="validateForm.usernameInput.$dirty" ng-messages="validateForm.usernameInput.$valid">
                            <div class="valid-message" ng-message="valid">valid!</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

</form
```

I also tried to set "ng-message" with the $valid ng-model but to no avail. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your form wasn't named
- the value of `ng-messages` should be an object containing a property/properties that you want to validate against. eg `input.$error` can have in your case `required`,`minlength` or `maxlength`. its different for `$valid` because that has true/false values, so we check for the property `$valid` on the object `usernameInput` for `true`/`false`
- the value of `ng-message` should be the name of the property to check on the containing block's `ng-messages` value object. if the value of the property is truthy you see the content, and you dont if its falsy.
- `ng-messages`/`ng-message` probably isnt the right solution for your case since you're checking one value and displaying one message.

TLDR

- `ng-messages` : name of object*
- `ng-message` : name of property of object*
- if the value of property is truthy, content of `ng-message` shows... falsy, nothing shows.

```js
angular.module('formDemo', ['ngMessages']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.20/angular-messages.js"></script>

<body ng-app="formDemo">
  <form name="validateForm">
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="inputSuccess">Username</label>
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <input 
        type="text" 
        id="inputUser"
        name="usernameInput"
        class="form-control textbox"
        placeholder="Digite seu Username"
        width="25"
        ng-model="username.value"
        ng-minlength="4"
        ng-maxlength="10"
        required>
        <div ng-if="validateForm.usernameInput.$dirty" ng-messages="validateForm.usernameInput.$error">
          <div class="error-message" ng-message="required">*This field is required</div>
          <div class="error-message" ng-message="minlength">*Username too short</div>
          <div class="error-message" ng-message="maxlength">*Username too long</div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="validateForm.usernameInput.$dirty" ng-messages="validateForm.usernameInput">
          <div class="valid-message" ng-message="$valid">valid!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

add "required" attribute to the input tag

else to avoid manipulation through inspection-tool, PHP works,

if(empty($_POST['usernameInput']))
{
echo "Error!"
}

Comment: I believe he's trying to do this with angular

Comment: yes, I'm trying to do this using pure AngularJS. And I already have a required attribute in my input

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `ng-if` with `validateForm.usernameInput.$valid` to control showing `valid messages`. mention that this block should be put outside `ng-message` block.

```
<div ng-if="validateForm.usernameInput.$valid">
  valid!
</div>
```

**[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/w2qmbnpm7nlnVbhylbiY?p=preview)**

comment: you missed `validateForm` at your `form` tag, I think this is typo.